# Си, добавление и удаление элементов стека

Tags: c, функции, динамические-массивы, стек, односвязный-список

Задача:
Написать подпрограммы для работы со стеком. И потом программу которая просто вызывает эти подпрограммы по очереди.

Подпрограммы написал, но не могу добавить элемент в стек с помощью этой подпрограммы. Когда задал вопрос на одном форуме тип почему не работает, мне сказали, что у меня какая то странная смесь Си и С++ которая никогда работать не будет, это меня совсем запутало :( 
Поэтому спрашиваю тут, что лучше исправить в этих подпрограммах и как с помощью них добавить элемент в стек?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
typedef struct STACK
{
    int info;
    STACK* next;
};
int Empty(STACK* p)
{
    if (p == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
void Add(STACK** p, int l)
{
    STACK* tmp = new STACK;
    tmp->info = l;
    tmp->next = *p;
    *p = tmp;
}
int Del(STACK** p)
{
    int j;
    j = (*p)->info;
    STACK* tmp = *p;
    *p = (*p)->next;
    delete tmp;
    return j;
}
void Show(STACK* p)
{
    STACK* tmp = p;

    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d", tmp->info);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}
void create(STACK** u)
{
    *u = NULL;
}
int main()
{
    {
        STACK* STACK = NULL;
        int num, l;
        char otv;
        printf("%d сколько элементов добавить?");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            Add(&STACK, l);

        printf("%d Элементы добавлены");
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, если его немного причесать - все работает... Предельные случаи не исправлял, сами смотрите - ну, там, удаление из пустого стека или что-то подобное, потому как с вашим кодом, например, при удалении из пустого стека вы таки получите немного сердцебиения :)

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct STACK_
{
    int info;
    struct STACK_* next;
} STACK;

int Empty(STACK* p)
{
    if (p == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
void Add(STACK** p, int l)
{
    STACK* tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));
    tmp->info = l;
    tmp->next = *p;
    *p = tmp;
}
int Del(STACK** p)
{
    int j;
    j = (*p)->info;
    STACK* tmp = *p;
    *p = (*p)->next;
    free(tmp);
    return j;
}
void Show(STACK* p)
{
    STACK* tmp = p;

    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        printf("  %d", tmp->info);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    puts("");
}
void create(STACK** u)
{
    *u = NULL;
}
int main()
{
    STACK* STACK = NULL;
    int num;
    printf("сколько элементов добавить? ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        Add(&STACK, i);

    printf("Элементы добавлены");

    Show(STACK);

    Del(&STACK);
    Del(&STACK);

    Show(STACK);

}
```

Comment: Хаха, да, именно из за new и delete на меня наехали и начали говорить, что мой препод не понимает, какой язык преподает вообще. Разве их нельзя использовать вместо free и malloc? Просто в универе почему то так учили, именно new, а не malloc

Comment: Если это C - нельзя, их в C просто нет. Если new и delete - то это уже C++. Так что это был не наезд, а констатация факта.

Comment: Да, спасибо. А почему VS ошибку выдает при запуске этой программы на строчке STACK* tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));. "значение типа "void*" нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа "STACK*"

Comment: Потому что вы **компилируете его как С++!!!** Дайте файлу расширение не .cpp, а .c, или укажите соответствующие параметры в проекте VC++. И, если ответ устраивает - закрывайте вопрос, пометив ответ как принятый.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, благодаря вам я понял, в чем заблуждался и дописал программу)